# Inputting variables from GET into a SQL Database not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get

I'm trying to insert variables from $_GET into a MySQL Database. I am a noob and I can't figure out what is wrong with it! The code runs and it outputs the user and userid added to table but when I check in phpMyAdmin

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$host = "host";
$database = "database";
$input_username = $_GET["username"];
$input_userId = $_GET["userId"];
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Couldn't select database: " . $database);
$sql = "INSERT INTO  users( UserId ,  Username )        VALUES('$_GET['userId']','$_GET['username']');";
echo "Username: " . $input_username . ", UserId: " . $input_userId ." added to table.";
mysql_close();
```

EDIT: I altered the code to fit the replied answers but now I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in PAGEPATH on line 10

Comment: Good thing it's not working. You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You also have absolutely **NO** error handling and are blindly assuming everything will work perfectly and NEVER fail.

Comment: @fred: I'd -infinite if I could. You just introduced syntax errors,

Comment: I did? @MarcB Lordie Lordie. Ok then. Scratch that (OP) I hate `mysql_*` lol

Comment: To: (OP) Do read up on this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php as per Marc's comment on SQL injection.

Comment: @fred. You can't quote array keys in a double-quoted string, unless you're using `{}` notation. `"$arr['bad'] {$arr['good']} $arr[good]"`.

Comment: I've made a note of that Marc, thanks. @MarcB

Comment: @JakeGould How would I fix it then?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't execute the query!
Add :

```
    $db = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Couldn't select database: " . $database);

 $userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["userid"]);
 $userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["username"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO  users(  UserId ,  Username ) 
VALUES ('". $userId  ."','". $userName  ."');";

        mysql_query($sql, $db);
```

Comment: You're right JakeGould it's why i just answer the basic question :)

Comment: downvote will be harsh but @PeteR right. if OP doesn't realise now, he never will.

Comment: @JakeGould: Yes, you are quite right. Why should I, or anyone else,  actually give a crap? It's not my site, downvote retracted.

Comment: This will be a bit more safe @Adam S

Answer (score 1):

Try this i have remove  `;` and  add `mysql_query($sql);`

```
<?php
$username = "sd";
$password = "asd";
$host = "sad";
$database = "asd";


$input_username = $_GET["username"];
$input_userId = $_GET["userId"];

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Couldn't select database: " . $database);

$sql = "INSERT INTO  users(  UserId ,  Username ) 
VALUES ('$_GET[userid]','$_GET[username]')";
mysql_query($sql);

echo "Username: " . $input_username . ", UserId: " . $input_userId ." added to table.";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: erm... have you **really** just put your username and password there?

Comment: No - the answer has no edits.  They were there from the original post.

Comment: i have just copy and paste and add  changes

Comment: Removed them and data base. I can't believe I forgot to remove them in the first place.

Comment: Yes,some time we forgot normal things

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you want to use a so vulnerable code, your sql must looks like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  users(  UserId ,  Username ) 
VALUES ('".$_GET["userid"]."','".$_GET["username"]."');";
mysql_query($sql, $db);
```

Comment: **execute the query**